# text - binary conversion

Tags: python, c++, c, binary

I'm trying to make a python program that converts text to one long binary string. The usual line of test and sentences are easy enough to convert into binary but I'm having trouble with the whitespace.
How do I put in a binary byte to represent the enter key?

Do I just put in the '/' and an 'n' strings?

I would ideally want to be able to convert an entire text file into a binary string and be able to convert it back again. Obviously, if I were to do this with a python script, the tabbing would get messed up and the program would be broken.

Would a C language be better for doing this stuff?

Obviously a C program would still function without its whitespace whereas python would not.

In short, I need to know how to represent the 'tab' and 'enter' keys in binary, and how to create a function to translate them into binary. would bin(ord('\n')) be good?

Comment: Please clarify "one long binary string".  Do you mean a bunch of '1' and '0' characters without and spaces between them?  For a quick size estimate, take the number of characters in the text, and multiply by 8, which will give you the size of your binary string.

Comment: Since you appear to talk about ASCII, why not look up the values for Tab and Enter?

Comment: Since you are converting from one file to another, you shouldn't need to concern yourself with Python's literal representation of the characters. As usual it would be a good idea to show the part you do have working in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tab is represented in the ASCII chart as <s>0x08</s> 0x09, or <s>"00001000"</s> "00001001" in a binary string.

The Enter key is different because it could represent CR (carriage return), LF (Linefeed), or both.

The CR is represented as 0x0d, or "00001101" as binary string.
The LF is represented as 0x0A, or "00001010" as binary string.

A common convention is '\t' for tab and '\r' for CR, '\n' for newline.

Comment: The common convention may work for the OP but this then needs another common convention: doubling backslashes to represent one.

Answer (score 0):

What about a simple:

```
def text_to_bits(text):
    bytes = text.encode('utf8')
    bits = [bin(ord(c))[2:].zfill(8) for c in bytes]
    return ''.join(bits)
```

This will use exactly the bytes in `text` (once encoded into `utf8` -- which will be innocuous if `text` is ASCII to start with, but indispensable if it's Unicode!-) so no convention or other arrangement is needed -- you'll get a string of `0`s and `1`s, eight bit per byte.

As @gnibbler's comment rightly points out, if `text` is hundreds of characters long, a lookup table will be faster, e.g, replacing the previous `bits =` with two lines:

```
lookup = {c: bin(c))[2:].zfill(8) for c in range(256)}
bits = [lookup[ord(c)] for c in bytes]
```

Alternatively, `lookup` could equally well be a list:

```
lookup = [bin(c))[2:].zfill(8) for c in range(256)]
```

All of these should work the same, pick the combination of speed and clarity that works best for you!-)

Comment: You can use a lookup list to make this faster if there is a lot of text. eg. `A = [format(c, "08b") for c in range(256)]` and then `[A[c] for c in bytes]`

Comment: Excellent suggestion, edited the A to introduce the lookup alternative (and the `ord` we both had forgotten:-).  Whether `format` or `bin + zfill` is faster (ditto, list vs dict for lookup table) needs to be microbenchmarked with `-mtimeit`, though your `format` idea **does** enjoy more readability, I think.